# Having performance problems linked to inactive input

Tags: hard-drive, graphics-card, cpu, performance, power-supply

I'm having a peculiar issue where if I leave my computer unattended and I'm using the system at an above normal pace, the performance will drop to almost 0, stuttering to refresh output every 5 or 6 seconds until I input with the mouse or keyboard. I've asked Reddit and they're completely baffled, thought I'd pass it through here to see if anyone's experienced this before.

## -- Hardware --

MOBO: ASUS 970 GAMING/AURA

GFX Card: GTX 970 overclocked with power at 120, temp limit at 85, memory to +450, and core to +100

CPU: AMD FX 8350 @4.3 GHz

HD: Seagate hybrid of some sort, 1 TB in size, I can fetch the model number if it's important for whatever reason

PSU: EVGA 600 +90 Watt (100-W1-0600-K1) - Heard some things about this line, but I'm going to assume it's not the culprit because I didn't have this issue a month ago on the same power supply, could be just be me wanting to save a buck though

RAM: 16 GB

OS: Windows 10 latest distribution

Full diagnostic for more in-depth hardware specifications: https://pastebin.com/fC4uK2Ft

### -- Steps already taken --

1. Ran TronScript, which automates disc cleanup, defrag, virus and malware torching, among other disc related performance degradation
2. Benchmarked CPU and GPU separately using Prime95 and Furmark, as far as I can tell the CPU test yielded no performance drops while the GPU test did
3. Undoing the overclock and retesting, same result
4. Ran memtest86+ for 12 hours and found 0 errors
5. Scanned the drive using HDTune and had all green across the board
6. Updated chipset, graphics card, and other outstanding drivers
7. Flashed the BIOS with the most recent version
8. Benchmarked using a clean boot, same problems
9. Ensured I was on high performance power mode, hibernation was off, fast startup was off, and sleep settings were set to never.
10. [Ran a powercfg /energy report](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=16889745743986221288)

Comment: What do you mean by "*I leave my computer unattended and I'm using the system at an above normal pace*"  because if you leave your computer unattended then how in the world are YOU using it let alone at an unusually abnormal pace? These statements contradict each other Jared so you may want to clarify what you are doing here excactly with this regard.

Comment: I meant that when I'm not in direct contact with my mouse or keyboard but still using the system to watch video or using an external controller